# More efficient way to fuzzy match large datasets in SAS

Tags: merge, sas, large-data, proc-sql, fuzzy-comparison

I have a dataset with over 33 million records that includes a name field. I need to flag records where this name field value also appears in a second dataset that includes about 5 million records.  For my purposes, a fuzzy match would be both acceptable and beneficial.

I wrote the following program to do this. It works but has been thus far running for 4 days, so I'd like to find a more efficient way to write it.

```
proc sql noprint;
   create table INDIV_MATCH as
   select A.NAME, SPEDIS(A.NAME, B.NAME) as SPEDIS_VALUE, COMPGED(A.NAME,B.NAME) as COMPGED_SCORE
   from DATASET1 A join DATASET2 B
   on COMPGED(A.NAME, B.NAME) le 400 and SPEDIS(A.NAME, B.NAME) le 10
   order by A.name;
quit;
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you remove exact matches first?

Comment: SAS has text processing engines available that would probably be more appropriate for this; do you license SAS Visual Analytics or any of the Machine Learning / Neural Network stuff?

Comment: Charles Patridge has been sharing his fuzzy match processes for a long time.  Take a read "The Fuzzy Feeling SAS Provides: Electronic
Matching of Records without Common Keys" http://ftp.sas.com/techsup/download/observations/obswww15/obswww15.pdf

Comment: Reeza, I did remove exact matches first but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Joe, Unfortunately, I don't have a license for SAS Visual Analytics or much above the base SAS platform.